# What does dis.findlabels() do?

Tags: python

I was playing around with the `dis` library to gather information about a function (like what other functions it called).  The documentation for [`dis.findlabels`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.findlabels) sounds like it would return other function calls, but I've tried it with a handful of functions and it always returns an empty list.

> ```
> dis.findlabels(code)
>
> Detect all offsets in the code object code which
> are jump targets, and return a list of these offsets.
> ```

What is this function *supposed* to do and *how* would you use it?

Comment: Use `dis.findlabels(f.__code__.co_code)` and make sure that f has a jump target in it (e.g. a conditional break statement in a for loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, this function has one jump:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 0:     # This will jump to "return 2" if not x > 0
        return 1
    else:
        return 2
```

See it here:

```
>>> dis.disco(f.__code__)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             15 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

There is one jump to 16 in `9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16`

Therefore, `findlabels` finds that jump target:

```
>>> dis.findlabels(f.__code__.co_code)
[16]
```

Answer (score 2):

The jump targets are annotated by `>>` in disassembly output.

For example, in:

```
def f(i):
    if i == 1:
        return 1
    elif i == 2:
        return 2
```

`dis.dis(f)` shows:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        

  4     >>   16 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             22 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             25 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32

  5          28 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             31 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             35 RETURN_VALUE
```

And `dis.findlabels(f.__code__.co_code)` returns `[16, 32]`.

Comment: Haha, that is almost the same as my example. Great minds think alike, right? ;)

Comment: Could you explain what the numbers in the disassembly refer to?

Comment: @wim First column: line numbers; 3rd column: bytecode offsets, 5th column: bytecode arguments (which may be bytecode offsets).

Comment: Is there any reason why these are called labels? Why not just call it find_jump_targets?

Comment: @InAFlash it's almost certainly from C, where the target of a `goto` (or a `case` in a `switch`) is called a label.

Comment: Oh.. Thank you. That makes sense.